# add another refer domain in HTTP_REFERER

Tags: php

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "https://domain1.com/"))
```

How to add another domain `https://domain2.com/` in this PHP code

Comment: We need to see the rest of the code, that doesn't mean anything by itself.

Comment: code is used for Reffer.. example link will open if  redirected from domain1.com if not refer to another page.. i want to add another domain

Comment: It still doesn't make sense. What you posted isn't code, it's just a variable and a string, it doesn't show how they're being used.

Comment: Maybe you want something like `if (in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], ['https://domain1.com/', 'https://domain2.com']))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), but you should also parse out just the domain, as referer contains the complete URL, not just the domain.

Example (https://3v4l.org/o4MmW):

```
<?php

$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] = 'http://example.com/foo/bar?baz=1';

//
if (in_array(parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST), [
    //
    'example.com', 
    'www.example.com',
    //
    'domain1.com',
    'www.domain1.com',
    //
    'domain2.com',
    'www.domain2.com'
])) {
    echo 'In referer';
} else {
    echo 'Not in referer';
}
```